# Use ratio test to determine convergence. Trig in numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this question:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{\frac{n\pi}{3}}}{n!}$$

I am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

$$\biggr\lbrack \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \biggr\rbrack = \biggr\lbrack \frac{\cos{\frac{n+1\pi}{3}}}{(n+1)!} * \frac{n}{\cos{\frac{n \pi}{3}}}\biggr\rbrack$$

Comment: The cosines are bounded. What happens to the denominator $n$ gets larger?

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to demonstrate that each term of your series is no larger (in absolute value) than a term of a series that you can prove (via the ratio test) converges.

Comment: Have noticed that $$\left |\frac {\cos \left ( \frac {n \pi} {3} \right ) } {(n+1)!} \right | \leq \frac {1} {n^2},$$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$?

Answer (score 0):

Just note that
$$
\left| \frac{\cos(n \pi /3)}{n!}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n!}
$$

and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$ is convergent.

Comment: I guess we wind up having convergent series * convergent series = another convergent series?

Comment: @Jwan622 It is not that. What we have is that a series with positive terms that is dominated by a convergent series is convergent.

Comment: I am told to use the ratio test... is there a way to use it here?

Comment: @Jwan622 you can use the ratio test to show the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$